# Horizontal scrolling with jQuery Tag-it

Tags: jquery, css, tag-it

I'm using [jQuery Tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) for something I'm working on. However, I don't like that whenever I type too many tags, the overflow appears below the tags I've already typed as opposed to just appending the newer tags to the right of whatever I've already typed.

What I want is to have tags always be appended to the right of the other tags, and allow a user to scroll horizontally to see new tags.

Here's the example page which I've been trying to play with: http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html

Here's my first try:

`ul.tagit { height: 40px; overflow-x: auto; }`

Second try:

```
ul.tagit { height: 40px; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap; }
ul.tagit li { display: inline; }
```

Neither seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you create a fiddle. this seems like its working using `inline` http://jsfiddle.net/REgGC/

Comment: I'll create a fiddle. However, if you try changing the CSS as you've provided on your fiddle to the example page I gave, it does not work

Comment: Here's a fiddle. Just copied stuff from the example page from the Github Repo http://jsfiddle.net/2hKY5/1/

Comment: Here's the fiddle with your CSS applied... http://jsfiddle.net/2hKY5/2/   <--- as you can see it still spills over onto the new line

Comment: Start typing stuff into the box. You'll see that the tags spill over into the second line instead of expanding to the right.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2hKY5/4/ <--- If you type a few tags into the input box here, it'll be more clear that it isn't working.

Comment: change li to `inline-block`

Comment: One other thing -- you'll notice if you type a few tags and then delete one (by typing delete twice) the tag will pop down to the second line. Any way to remove this effect?

Comment: i tried the code above and i'm also having the same problem when you  erase a tag, by any chance you have solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The code from btevfik found under works:
http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/qUsG8/

The problem I encountered  however with that piece of code was, that when removing tags the `<ul>` popped down to a second line and immediately jumped up again when the tag was removed. This can be solved by setting 
`animate: false` 
in the tag-it.js file.